# How can I achieve non-overlapping circles/icons on a d3 time scale?

Tags: d3.js

I am placing icons with a fixed diameter/radius on a line using `d3.scaleTime`. This works well except for the case in which dates are close to one another, leading to an unwanted overlap.

In that specific case, I would want the icons to "relax" and not touch.

My code rather complex, including animations etc. — so I drew the problem here:

[image]

These are my attempts:

- I looked at `d3-force` for collision prevention, but I was not quite sure how to merge such an approach with an existing time scale. Could this be helpful? http://jsbin.com/gist/fee5ce57c3fc3e94c3332577d1415df4 However, it may occur that the icons then do not align on a horizontal straight line anymore, which is a disadvantage, because I do not want them to spread vertically.
- I also thought about calculating overlaps and then manually adjusting the data so that the overlap does not occur. That, however seems a bit more complex because I would have to somehow recursively find the best position for every icon.
- Could interpolation help me? I thought there must be something like "snap to grid", but then two icons could snap to the same position, couldn't they?

Which d3 concept makes most sense to solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure which behaviour you're expecting when overlap occurs, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50939620/d3-dynamic-binning-for-single-axis-zoomable-timeline) might help.

Comment: `That, however seems a bit more complex because I would have to somehow recursively find the best position for every icon.`, you'll have that problem with any solution.  What is your desired outcome on that position?

Comment: Relaxing horizontal position of the dots will decrease the accuracy of your chart, negatively affecting the interpretavility of the figures. If you are ready to do this, [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150122091143/https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/03/11/solving-d3-label-placement-constraint-relaxing/)  explains an approach, can be easily adapted to circles instead of labels. I may be able to help if you create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a snippet.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I found your hints useful but eventually decided to try the force layout. However, I am not getting the results I am looking for, so I rephrased the question with your feedback here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109918/position-circles-on-a-horizontal-axis-without-overlapping-using-d3s-force-layou

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Position circles on a horizontal axis without overlapping using d3's force layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109918/position-circles-on-a-horizontal-axis-without-overlapping-using-d3s-force-layou)